Problem with nodemon in Docker container. Change detected, page not updating
I've googled this to death. I see other people have the same problem, i've tried their solution, but it's not working for me. The problem in a nutshell is that i'm running a container with a node app. I use nodemon to see changes to my code 'live', I can see that the changes to the code are being detected since the console says this every time i save a change in the code:

When i make a change, it does not update in my browser, I have to manually refresh the page to see the change.

dashboard-app  | [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
dashboard-app  | [nodemon] starting node app.js
dashboard-app  | Server is running on http://localhost:3000
Here is my code. Let's start with my docker-compose.yml for the app:
dashboard-app:
    container_name: dashboard-app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app  # Mount your project directory correctly
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: nodemon -L app.js
    networks:
      - my-network
    restart: always

Than my Dockerfile:
FROM node:16

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install all dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy all other files
COPY . .

# Install nodemon globally
RUN npm install -g nodemon

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run nodemon
CMD ["npm", "start"]


and my package.json:
{
  "name": "my-node-dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A dashboard for business tools and stats",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -L app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}


I believe that this is everything affecting this perticular problem.
Anyone see any errors? Or have a tip for solving it?
Other solutions to this problem mainly revolve arround using the -L tag in the nodemon command.
And / OR adding enviroment chokidar_usepolling=true. This has not worked for me.

This question is similar to: Node.js - Auto Refresh In Dev. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm kinda new to Stack Overflow, so i'm sorry if I've broken any norms here. I guess the question/problem is not different, but the solution for previous posts did not work for my problem. That's why I posted a new question. Maybe that's not the way to go forth here. I'm sorry.

This question is similar to: Nodemon not refreshing browser in React-Express-Node App. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

nodemon won't refresh your browser, it only tracks server changes.
Please see answer here or here. You need to setup something like livereload, browsersync, etc. along with nodemon to make it work

Please flag this question as a duplicate, rather than leaving an answer with just pointers to other questions.

@DavidMaze Oh, alright

@Pavolo Sobchuk I'll look into browsersync or livereload. Thanks for the tip :)
But from what I've gathered from simular questions/problems, it should be possible with just nodemon. I might be wrong, but i seems that adding the "-L" has worked for alot of people, just not me :(

consider adding
"nodemonConfig": {
    "legacyWatch": true
}

to your package.json

Is this different from the nodemon -L option in the overridden Compose command:?

-L is for legacywatch, its just recommended to add the config to your package.json, however i have never had the need to explicitly add the config, usually -L is enough, which makes me wonder if there's something else we are missing here.
I would recommend changing your files inside your docker container directly and seeing if it reloads your server or not

From what i've gathered -L is just shortform of --legacy-watch. So I believe i've tried this.

This file should resolve the issue:
services:
  simple-express-app:
    container_name: simple-express-app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app  # Mount your project directory correctly
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: nodemon -L app.js
    networks:
      - my-network
    restart: always
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge


This looks almost identical to what' in the question; what's different?

What @David Maze said. This is the same, you just added "services:" to the top. I have that in my script aswell, but i've got like 7 services running, i did'nt want to include the whole thing, the other services are working like they should, and have nothing to do with this problem :)

When I run your yml file it does not work. But when I run my yml file it work properly when I add networks.

I did not post my entire .yml file. I just posted the part about the service that inpacted my problem.
